# Analyzing time complexity of k-way merge operation for merge sort

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort, array-merge

I am trying to analyze the complexity of merge procedure for merge sort to combine k sorted arrays with n elements  into a single sorted array of kn elements 
**My understanding so far on this:**

1. **Step 1:** Firstly creating an output array of size n*k then create a
   min heap of size k and insert first element in all the arrays into a
   heap.

   2. **Step 2**:Then get minimum element from heap(which always at
      root) and store it in an output array and replace heap root with
      next element from the array from which the element is extracted.If
      doesn't have any more elements in array then replace with infinite.
2. **Step 3**: Repeat the 2nd step n*k times.

This approach of merging sorted arrays takes **O(nk*Logk)** time using Min Heap.

**Please suggest with some more ideas and detailed explanation.** Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have got more explanation here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I mean , Is this explanation / analysis is good enough or need more for analyzing the time complexity of merging procedure in merge sort?